# Upgrade PhoneGap/Cordova version in the SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS

Tags: phonegap, mobile

Currently the SalesforceMobileSDK for iOS (https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) comes with Cordova 1.8.1. Current version of Cordova is 2.1.0.
Now I'm facing a desperate need for a Cordova feature implemented after v1.8.1 (in my case the ability to add header parameters to a FileTransfer request http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer implemented in Cordova 1.9.0)

Therefore my question is:
1) How would I go about upgrading the Cordova version used in my project? Or is this not a way to go?

2) What are the SalesforceMobileSDK project's strategy for staying up to date with Cordova releases?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow may be better place to get this quickly as there will be more mobile app devlopers

Comment: This sounds like a good question for @metadaddy

Comment: +1 as I faced the same problem, but not sure if SE is good platform for the same. Another way could be Idea-Exchange idea with new features we will get with upgrade, we all can help by up-voting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not currently an easy way to upgrade your Cordova version within the Salesforce Hybrid SDK, as the current architecture has it embedded within the Hybrid SDK framework itself.  I would say, for practical purposes, that's probably not the way to go at this point.  Let me speak to your second question.

First, we are actively working towards being on the latest version of Cordova, in our next release.  Our tentative timeframe for this release will be early December.  In the meantime, however, we do all of our development against the public repo, in our [unstable branch](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/tree/unstable)(es).  So early drops of our work will be available there.

Second, one of the reasons we've been working to get in sync with the latest version of Cordova is so that we can have a foundation for actively contributing changes back to [the Apache project](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/), rather than maintaining customizations within our own fork.  That said, we'll probably still maintain our own fork of the main project, to allow for the intervening time between Apache commits and current customer requirements.  Moving forward, we will be doing our best to stay in sync with the latest versions of Cordova, as they move forward with their release cycle.

Finally, in a Mobile SDK release down the road (probably a major revision for the Mobile SDK), we will be decoupling Cordova from the Hybrid SDK, allowing it to be a side-by-side first-class citizen/dependency with the SDK framework itself.  So in the future, Hybrid SDK consumers will be able to much more easily swap different versions of Cordova in and out of their own projects.  There will still exist the potential for version compatibility issues in that use case, but managing those dependencies will generally be a lot more manageable than it currently is.